# Any idea how to fix this error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'" in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, typeerror

I am trying to implement a Differential Evolution Algorithm for a traveling salesmen problem.
I am getting the following error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'"
I understand that I can not subtract two lists but I am not sure what to do exactly to fix this issue. Thank you for your help.
The effected part of the code is:

```
        x_1 = population[random_index[0]]
        x_2 = population[random_index[1]]
        x_3 = population[random_index[2]]
        x_t = population[random_index[3]]
        print("X_t", x_t)

        # subtract x3 from x2, and create a new vector (x_diff)
        x_diff = [x_2_i - x_3_i for x_2_i, x_3_i in zip(x_2, x_3)]

        # multiply x_diff by the mutation factor (F) and add to x_1
        v_donor = [x_1_i + mutate * x_diff_i for x_1_i, x_diff_i in zip(x_1, x_diff)]
        v_donor = ensure_bounds(v_donor, bounds)
```

Comment: You don't say, but I assume the error is in 'x_diff = [x_2_i - x_3_i for x_2_i, x_3_i in zip(x_2, x_3)]'? Can you edit your question to provide examples of what x_2 and x_3 might contain and what you would expect the resulting x_diff to be?

Answer (score 1):

The following does work:

```
>>> x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]                                                                                          
>>> x2 = [2,2,2,2,2]                                                                                           
>>> print([x_1_i - x_2_i for x_1_i, x_2_i in zip(x1, x2)])

[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Maybe your input is not scalar?